# Error Connecting Neo4j from java

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to connect neo4j from java class however im getting following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No label scan store provider org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.scan.LabelScanStoreProvider found. Kernel extensions available on classpath:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what it says and add all necessary jars on the classpath.

Best to use a build-system like maven, gradle and declare the dependency:

```
org.neo4j:neo4j:2.0.1
```

Then everything needed will be pulled in automatically.

Comment: I hv added jar files , now im getting err-
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/index/IndexNotFoundException
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException
though i hv included neo4j-lucene-index-2.1.0-M01.jar file 
which jar file should i include for lucene index? plz guide